# Array traversal in JavaScript to fill two maps

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

```js
var numerList = [1, 3, 7, 2, 4, 16, 22, 23];
var evenNoLst = numerList.map(function(no) {
  return ((no % 2) === 0);
});
console.log(evenNoLst)
```

Above code for me is creating a map of even numbers, now I also want to have odd number list. Do I need to traverse through number list again? or is there a way to have two maps using single traversal of an array.

I am using Javascript.

Comment: Thank You All, I have accepted the answer I used.

Comment: Just as a matter of interest and an exercise in performance, I have timed each of the given answers, and interestingly the accepted answer is more than 10 times slower than any of the other answers. [See here for the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/declanmcd/qmmyyz2o/)

Comment: Your use maps to refer to arrays (instead of dictionaries) (just because you use that function?). Then your intent of creating numberlists does not correspond with your example creating booleanlists. Lots of confusion going on...

Comment: @hkBst Second this. Apparently everyone answering the question has correctly assumed the question is about filtering even and odd numbers, meaning the the code in the question should look like the answer by Ramesh Rajendran...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could take the logical NOT operator and map all boolean values.

```js
var numerList = [1, 3, 7, 2, 4, 16, 22, 23],
    evenNoLst = numerList.map(no => no % 2 === 0),
    oddNoLst = evenNoLst.map(b => !b);

console.log(evenNoLst);
console.log(oddNoLst);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

With a single loop approach

```js
var numerList = [1, 3, 7, 2, 4, 16, 22, 23],
    oddNoLst = [],
    evenNoLst = [];

numerList.forEach(function (no) {
    var even = no % 2 === 0;
    evenNoLst.push(even);
    oddNoLst.push(!even);
});

console.log(evenNoLst);
console.log(oddNoLst);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

With `for ... of` loop

```js
var numerList = [1, 3, 7, 2, 4, 16, 22, 23],
    oddNoLst = [],
    evenNoLst = [],
    no, even;

for (no of numerList) {
    even = no % 2 === 0;
    evenNoLst.push(even);
    oddNoLst.push(!even);
}

console.log(evenNoLst);
console.log(oddNoLst);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I used single loop approach

Comment: That "single loop" approach is so ugly… `map` doesn't go well with side effects.

Comment: @Bergi Agreed, one should do a normal iteration and push on both lists without doing it inside a `map`

Comment: Thanks, better :-) (of course I still prefer `for … of` over `forEach`)

Comment: @Bergi, does it have a reason, or is it just a favorite method for iterating?

Comment: @NinaScholz It makes imperative code look imperative. And it allows to use control flow keywords like `yield`, `await`, `return`, `break` and `continue`. Also it's a bit shorter.

Answer (score 20):

Here's a way to split it in one go with [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
var numberList = [1, 3, 7, 2, 4, 16, 22, 23];

var grouped = numberList.reduce(function (acc, x){  
  acc[x%2].push(x);
  return acc;
}, [[], []]);

console.log(grouped);
```

The result is an array with two arrays inside: the first one has the even numbers and the second one the odd ones.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `array.prototype.reduce` and some `destructuring`:

```js
var numberList = [1, 3, 7, 2, 4, 16, 22, 23];
var { evenList, oddList } = numberList.reduce((m, o) => {
    o % 2 === 0 ? m.evenList.push(o) : m.oddList.push(o);
    return m;
}, { evenList: [], oddList: []});

console.log("evenList: ", evenList);
console.log("oddList: ", oddList);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use lodash's groupBy is a more generic patten.

```js
var _ = require('lodash');

var numerList = [1, 3, 7, 2, 4, 16, 22, 23];

var result = _.groupBy(numerList, function(ele) {
  return ele%2;
});

console.log(result); //=> { '0': [ 2, 4, 16, 22 ], '1': [ 1, 3, 7, 23 ] }
```

If you need to group array to more than 2 group, for example 3 group, just

```js
var _ = require('lodash');

var numerList = [1, 3, 7, 2, 4, 16, 22, 23];

var result = _.groupBy(numerList, function(ele) {
  return ele%3;
});

console.log(result); //=> { '0': [ 3 ], '1': [ 1, 7, 4, 16, 22 ], '2': [ 2, 23 ] }
```